# Cannot create a view in SQL

Tags: sql-server

```
 Create view PercentPopulationVaccinated as 
Select dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date, dea.population, vac.new_vaccinations
,sum(convert(int,vac.new_vaccinations)) OVER (Partition by dea.location order by dea.location,
dea.date) as rolling_people_vaccinated
from PortfolioProject..['Covid vaccinations$'] vac
Join PortfolioProject..['Covid deaths$'] dea
     On dea.location=vac.location
     and dea.date=vac.date
where dea.continent is not null
--order by 2,3

Select * 
from PercentPopulationVaccinated
```

I want to create a view but I keep receiving this error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure PercentPopulationVaccinated, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 127]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 statements in this batch.  CREATE VIEW has to be the only statement in the batch.  Remove that 2nd SELECT statement from your batch.  If you are doing this in SSMS you can also add GO in between the CREATE VIEW statement and that last SELECT.

```
 Create view PercentPopulationVaccinated as 
Select dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date, dea.population, vac.new_vaccinations
,sum(convert(int,vac.new_vaccinations)) OVER (Partition by dea.location order by dea.location,
dea.date) as rolling_people_vaccinated
from PortfolioProject..['Covid vaccinations$'] vac
Join PortfolioProject..['Covid deaths$'] dea
     On dea.location=vac.location
     and dea.date=vac.date
where dea.continent is not null
--order by 2,3
GO

Select * 
from PercentPopulationVaccinated
```

Comment: It shows , "Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Procedure PercentPopulationVaccinated, Line 2 [Batch Start Line 126]
There is already an object named 'PercentPopulationVaccinated' in the database."  But it doesnt show up under the views folder

Comment: Right-click the views folder and choose Refresh.  Or click on the views folder and hit F5 which will also do a refresh.

Comment: Refreshed so many times. Still not showing

Comment: Then you probably weren't connected to the database you're currently looking at when you ran the script.  Could be that you were still set to the `master` db when you ran it, that bites me a lot when I'm not paying attention.  What does your connection info look like in your query window?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to smss so I'm not sure what you mean. How do I find out "the connection info in the query window?"

Comment: At the bottom of your query window tab it should show you what server and database you're connected to.  You can make sure you're in the correct database by adding `USE MyDatabase; GO` to the top.

Comment: Correct database. Still no views

Comment: While connected to the database your view should be in, run `SELECT [type] FROM sys.objects WHERE [name]='PercentPopulationVaccinated ';`  What does that give you?